# Reading a csv file with date variables using tidyverse

Tags: r

Hi I have data in a CSV file which has two date columns(1st and 3rd).
When I type in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- read_csv("Dynamic AA.csv", col_types = "DdDd")
```

It imports the data but both the date columns have only NA values. The data was not imported.
Following error is produced:

```
Warning: 8842 parsing failures.
row        col   expected   actual             file
  1 Date_Debt  date like  06/19/20 'Dynamic AA.csv'
  1 Date_NIFTY date like  06/19/20 'Dynamic AA.csv'
  2 Date_Debt  date like  06/18/20 'Dynamic AA.csv'
  2 Date_NIFTY date like  06/18/20 'Dynamic AA.csv'
  3 Date_Debt  date like  06/17/20 'Dynamic AA.csv'
... .......... .......... ........ ................
See problems(...) for more details.
```

The date is in the standard R format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the date format is not specified. Something like in the following should work.

```
mydata <- read_csv("Dynamic AA.csv", col_types = cols(
           Date_Debt  = col_date("%m/%d/%y"),
           scnd_col = col_double(),
           Date_NIFTY   = col_date("%m/%d/%y"),
           forth_col = col_double()))
```

Comment: Error: Unknown shortcut: %m/%g/%Y

Comment: I got this...Error: Unknown shortcut: %m/%d/%y

Comment: See the edit `col_types = cols(`. By the way, make sure to have the correct col names.